# Как получить доступ к нарисованному QPainter?

Tags: python, pyqt5, рисование, qpainter

Пишу на *Python* программу, которая выводит на `QLabel` фотографию при помощи `QPainter.drawPixmap`, чтобы потом рисовать на ней мышью произвольные каляки-маляки (закрашенные полигоны).

Конечная задача состоит в том, чтобы посчитать площадь закрашенных красным полигонов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не нашёл варианта лучше, чем тупо пересчитать пиксели определённого цвета.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно получить доступ к художествам, нарисованным `QPainter`.

Привожу код класса MegaLabel, который я сделал, чтобы реализовать обработку нажатия и выделения мышью над QLabel:

```py
    # This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPolygon, QPen, QBrush
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
    
    
    class MegaLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MegaLabel, self).__init__(parent=parent)
            self.selected_line = []  # отдельный выделенный пользлвателем полигон
            self.selected_lines = []  # массив всех полигонов
            self.image = QPixmap()  # картинка, на фоне которой происходит рисование
            self.scale_factor = 1.0  # отношение размера отображаемой картинки к реальному
    
        def paintEvent(self, event):
            painter = QPainter(self)
    
            if not self.image.isNull():  # отображение фоновой картинки
                painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.image)
    
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red, Qt.SolidPattern))
    
            # Отрисовка всех уже залитых полигонов
            for i in range(len(self.selected_lines)):  # преобразование координат от 1:1 к отображаемым
                transformed_line = [j * self.scale_factor for j in self.selected_lines[i]]
                painter.drawPolygon(QPolygon(transformed_line))
    
            # Отображение линии в процессе рисования
            transformed_line = [j * self.scale_factor for j in self.selected_line] # преобразование координат от 1:1 к отображаемым
            painter.drawPolyline(QPolygon(transformed_line))
    
        def mousePressEvent(self, event):  # при нажатии левой кнопкой начинают записываться координаты нового полигона
            if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
                self.selected_line = []
    
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):  # при нажатой кнопке происходит запись координат
            if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
                # Координаты выделения приводятся к координатам фонового рисунка в масштабе 1:1
                self.selected_line.append(event.pos() / self.scale_factor)
                self.update()
    
        def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):  # при отпускании кнопки список координат полигона передаётся в массив полигонов
            if event.button() & Qt.LeftButton:
                self.selected_lines.append(self.selected_line)
                self.update()
```

Comment: sorry, если не секрет - зачем вам площадь каляк-маляк?

Comment: Для реализации одного промышленного стандарта и для развития навыков в Python. Десять лет назад подобную программу написал на Delphi, пользователи попросили обновить - пытаюсь реализовать на Python.

Comment: pupinho, покажите, пожалуйста, ваш вариант, который у вас есть сейчас.

Comment: Добавил в основное сообщение код класса, который пришлось сделать для того, чтобы обрабатывать нажатия мышью над QLabel. Сейчас думаю, может быть всё это надо было реализовывать через QGraphicsScene & QGraphicsView?

Comment: pupinho, покажите, пожалуйста, как вы сейчас пересчитываете пиксели красного цвета

Comment: Наверное, я не очень понятно сформулировал основной вопрос. В том-то и дело, что я не могу понять, как их пересчитать. В этом и состоит вопрос: как получить доступ к тому что нарисовано QPainter? Т.е. к красным пискелям или пусть даже к красным, наложенным на фотографию.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге всё решилось отрисовкой на QImage, которая потом отрисовывалась на QLabel, код при этом упростился:

```py
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPolygon, QPen, QBrush, QImage
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
    
    
    class MegaLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MegaLabel, self).__init__(parent=parent)
            self.selected_line = []  # координаты полигона
            self.image = QImage()  # картинка, на которой происходит рисование
            self.scale_factor = 1.00  # отношение размера отображаемой картинки к реальному
    
        def paintEvent(self, event):
            painter = QPainter(self)
            if not self.image.isNull():
                painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image)
    
        def mousePressEvent(self, event):  # при нажатии левой кнопкой начинают записываться координаты нового полигона
            if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
                self.selected_line = []
    
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):  # при нажатой кнопке происходит запись координат
            if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
                impainter = QPainter(self.image)  # QPainter для image
                self.selected_line.append(event.pos() / self.scale_factor)  # Координаты выделения приводятся к координатам фонового рисунка в масштабе 1:1
                impainter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
                impainter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red, Qt.SolidPattern))
                impainter.drawPolyline(QPolygon(self.selected_line))
                self.update()
    
        def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):  # при отпускании кнопки список координат полигона передаётся в массив полигонов
            if event.button() & Qt.LeftButton:
                impainter = QPainter(self.image)  # QPainter для image
                impainter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
                impainter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red, Qt.SolidPattern))
                impainter.drawPolygon(QPolygon(self.selected_line))
                self.update()
```

QImage поддерживает требуемые операции, в том числе, на ней можно пересчитать пиксели требуемого цвета.